# SQL Query group data

Tags: sql, group-by

**I have data as below.**

```
     Group  Jan     Feb      Mar
---|------|-----|-------|--------|---------
   |   A  | I22 |       |        |
   |   A  |     | I22   |        |
   |   A  |     |       | I22    |
   |   B  | I33 |       |        |
   |   B  |     | I33   |        |
   |   B  |     |       | I33    |
```

**How is the query to make the data like this:-**

```
     Group  Jan     Feb      Mar
---|------|-----|-------|--------|---------
   |   A  | I22 | I22   |  I22   |
   |   B  | I33 | I33   |  I33   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group is a keyword so you'll need to escape it appropriately for your RDBMS (e.g., square brackets for SQL Server, backticks for MySQL, etc).

```
SELECT [Group], MAX(Jan), MAX(Feb), MAX(Mar)
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY [Group]
```

Comment: @Balconsky: How do you figure that?

Comment: This sort of escaping is why I tend to avoid columns after keywords (giving it a label for the _exact_ type of group would help in this regard).  I agree with using an aggregate in this regard (DB2 produces similar results), although you may need to check which order your system places `null` in (although I believe having it sort as 'least' in this situation is standard).